# enforcing only one required selection in radio box in html5

Tags: html

Dear Community I have the following code. How I can enforce the user only pick one but not both and make it a required field ??

```
<input type="radio" name="genderM" value="Male" >Male
<input type="radio" name="genderF" value="Female">Female <br> <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the radio buttons the same `name` attribute and add the `required` attribute

```html
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required>Female
```

I also recommend adding `<labels>` to make the fields more accessible. You should also validate the data on the server side as the `required` attribute only validates on the client side.

Note also that while the `required` attribute is only really needed on one radio button in a group, the [W3 recommends](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) that they all have it:

> To avoid confusion as to whether a radio button group is required or
>   not, authors are encouraged to specify the attribute on all the radio
>   buttons in a group. Indeed, in general, authors are encouraged to
>   avoid having radio button groups that do not have any initially
>   checked controls in the first place, as this is a state that the user
>   cannot return to, and is therefore generally considered a poor user
>   interface.